# Determining confidence interval for point estimate from regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, confidence-interval

Given a regression equation and confidence intervals for the coefficients, how do you compute a confidence interval around a point estimate derived from the regression equation? I'm specifically interested in the case of binary logistic regression.

As an example with made-up parameters, let's say I want to estimate at what BMI is risk for 10-year mortality equal to 50%. I run a logistic regression of mortality (binary) on BMI (continuous) and get the following parameters:

```r
intercept [95% CI]: -12.34 [-14.68, -10.00]
BMI [95% CI]: 0.89 [0.11, 1.67]
```

This gives Y-hat(survival) = -12.34 + 0.89 * BMI.

p(survival) = .5 when Y-hat survival = 0. So I can now solve for BMI when Y-hat = 0 and find

BMI = 12.34 / 0.89 = 13.87 when Y-hat = 0.

But how do I compute a 95% CI around the point estimate of 13.87? Do I solve the same equation using lower and upper bounds of the intercept and coefficient CIs? Is there some way of deriving the standard error of the point estimate, from which I can derive the confidence interval? Is my whole approach hopelessly confused?